# MPMoviePlayerViewController issue

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to add subview MPMoviePlayerViewController object, its top bar moves little bit down, but if i do presentView the MPMoviePlayerViewController object its perfect. ?
I dont know whats happening. Please help me out .

if i an adding on subview i am writing :

```
      self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL       URLWithString:self.filePath]];
       [self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
      [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
```

so top default  done button and progress bar moves little bit down.
Please help me , Why this is happening ? and solution for this.

Comment: moviePlayer.view.frame=CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0,480.0);

Answer (score 1):

```
    MPMoviePlayerController* movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
                                                initWithContentURL:url];

    movieController.view.frame = self.window.bounds;
    movieController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;   
    [self.window addSubview:movieController.view];

    [movieController prepareToPlay];
    [movieController setShouldAutoplay:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL       URLWithString:self.filePath]];

CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
frame.origin.y -= 20;
[self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:frame];
[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
```

The `MPMoviePlayerViewController` view frame is assuming that it will display with the status bar visible, but I am assuming you have hidden your status bar. So when you add the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` view, its frame.origin.y is set to 20 (status bar height).

Comment: Awesome Dude :) Thanks alot, its working, But one thing which i dont understand is I am not hidding my status bar , and still its working.            CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
frame.origin.y -= 20;
[self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:frame];

Comment: MPMoviePlayerViewController is usually displayed full screen, modally. So its frame is initialized as (0,20,screenWidth,screenWidth,screenHeight-20). When you reset its frame using [self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds], you changed the size, but not the origin so its origin.y is still set to 20.